# Firefox opens standard FB.login popup in a new tab instead of dialog

Tags: firefox, facebook

Using the stock code found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

FB.login is bound to a jquery click event on my button.
On Chrome it opens successfully in a popup.
On Firefox it opens in a new tab.

How do I get the popup back in Firefox?